# C# Error Editar detalle

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, knockoutjs

Actualmente tengo un error para editar el detalle de un pedido, quiero pasar el campo iCode que es el código del detalle, pero con el presente código tengo el error que pasa el código de la cabecera del pedido.

En mi vista el detalle es el siguiente:

```
<tbody style="background-color:#f1f8f8" data-bind="foreach: items">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text: iCode"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: strName"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: iQuantity"></td>
                            <td><a href="#" @{ if (Model.iShow > 0)
                                            { <text> style="visibility:hidden" </text> } } data-bind="click: $parent.EditDetalle">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

El codigo en javaScript es el siguiente:

```
self.EditDetalle = function () {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        debugger;
                        var sCode = $("#iCode").val()
                        window.location.href = "/Admin/ManagementRequest?iCode=" + sCode;
                    };
```

Por favor su apoyo para solucionar el error descrito. Gracias

Comment: ¿qué error tienes?

Comment: No esta pasando el parámetro código de detalle, si no que esta pasando el código de la cabecera y quiero pararle el iCode que se muestra en el vista indicada.

Comment: @DAES aún no queda claro, el miembro `data-bind="text iCode"` es el que **deseas pasar**, ¿o es  `strname`? ¿o `Detalle`? . En el caso del último no tiene un `data-bind` ya que, por lo visto, solo lo inicias con `<td>`

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún framework en el cliente? ¿Sí? Entonces ¿Cúal es? ¿No? Entonces ¿Cómo trabajas: `data-bind="foreach: items"`?

Comment: no veo C# ni ASP.net por ningun lado.

Comment: @Agustin M.  correcto `data-bind="text iCode"` es lo que necesito pasar a la funcion `self.EditDetalle` de javascript.

Comment: @fredixfx estoy ususando  `Knockou JS `.

Answer (score 0):

No se mucho de knockout.js pero puedo ver que aqui tienes un problema:

```
 var sCode = $("#iCode").val()
```

En el html que nos muestras no hay un elemento con el id `iCode` sino un binding por lo que seria imposible para jQuery obtener el valor de un input que no existe.

Modifica el html de manera que un `input[hidden]` pueda guardar el valor del `iCode`:

```
<tbody style="background-color:#f1f8f8" data-bind="foreach: items">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text: iCode">
               <input type="hidden" id="iCode" data-bind="{ value: iCode }" />

                     </td>
                            <td data-bind="text: strName"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: iQuantity"></td>
                            <td><a href="#" @{ if (Model.iShow > 0)
                                            { <text> style="visibility:hidden" </text> } } data-bind="click: $parent.EditDetalle">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

No puedo confirmar que el binding vaya a funcionar(hace mucho que no hago un desastre con knockout.js), pero *es para que tengas una idea de lo que debes de hacer para que funcione con jQuery*.

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, aun tengo el error si alguien conoce la sintaxis por favor su apoyo.